# Django's APPEND_SLASH adds slash, when there is an url pattern, but only if NO cyrillic letters in URL

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I wrote an app on site, to upload and serve mediafiles (to registered users).
Actually, files are served by nginx, using x-accel-redirect header.

When browser try to download e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/mediacontent/files/abc.pdf
it gets HTTP301 to "abc.pdf/", but if file contains cyrillic letters, e.g. "/файл.pdf", everything is ok, browser gets file!

Why ADD_SLASHES adds / to plain ASCII URL, while it's matches pattern?

Site also based on django-cms, if it makes difference.

urls.py:

```
(r'^mediacontent/', include('mediacontent.urls')),
```

mediacontent/urls.py:

```
url(r'^files/(?P<path>.*)$', login_required(serve_mediacontent), name="serve"),
```

views.py:

```
def serve_mediacontent(request, path):
    webserver = getattr(settings, 'WEBSERVER', 'nginx')
    if webserver == 'nginx':
        response = HttpResponse()
        response['Content-Type'] = ""
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = "/media/files/" + path.encode("utf-8")
        return response
```